# Icon not changing for password visibility, What am i doing wrong?

Tags: flutter, dart

```
import 'package:apex_memo/google_auth.dart';
import 'package:apex_memo/screens/home_screen.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:google_fonts/google_fonts.dart';
import 'package:icons_plus/icons_plus.dart';
import 'package:shared_preferences/shared_preferences.dart';
import '../constants.dart';
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:lottie/lottie.dart';

class LoginPage extends StatefulWidget {
  static String id = 'login_screen';

  @override
  State<LoginPage> createState() => LoginPageState();
}

class LoginPageState extends State<LoginPage> {
  static const String KEYLOGIN = "login";

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    whereToGo();
  }

  final _formkey = GlobalKey<FormState>();
  final _auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
  final _firestore = FirebaseFirestore.instance;
  String email = "";
  String password = "";
  String name = "";

  TextEditingController _email = TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController _password = TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController _name = TextEditingController();
  bool _obscuretext1 = true;
  bool _obscuretext2 = true;

  void _signInWithEmail() async {
    try {
      UserCredential userCredential = await _auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(
        email: _email.text.trim(),
        password: _password.text.trim(),
      );

      User? user = userCredential.user;

      if (user != null) {
        var sharedPref = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
        sharedPref.setBool(KEYLOGIN, true);
        Navigator.pushReplacement(
            context,
            MaterialPageRoute(
              builder: (context) => HomePage(),
            ));
      }
    } catch (e) {
      print(e);
    }
  }

  void _signUpWithEmail() async {
    if (password != null) {
      try {
        UserCredential userCredential =
            await FirebaseAuth.instance.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(
          email: email,
          password: password,
        );
        ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
          SnackBar(
            dismissDirection: DismissDirection.up,
            backgroundColor: Color(0xFF000000),
            content: Text(
              'Registered Successfully',
              style: kIntertextstylewhitemedium,
            ),
          ),
        );

        User? user = userCredential.user;

        if (user != null) {
          // Save user details to Firestore
          await _firestore.collection('users').doc(user.uid).set({
            'name': _name.text.trim(),
            'email': _email.text.trim(),
            'password': _password.text.trim(),
          });

          // Clear the form fields after successful sign up

          Navigator.pushReplacement(
            context,
            MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => HomePage()),
          );
        }

        if (user != null) {
          Navigator.pushNamed(context, HomePage.id);
        }
      } on FirebaseAuthException catch (e) {
        if (e.code == 'weak-password') {
          showDialog(
            context: context,
            builder: (context) => AlertDialog(
              backgroundColor: Color(0xFF226089),
              content: Text(
                'Password is weak',
                style: kIntertextstylewhitemedium,
              ),
            ),
          );
        } else if (e.code == 'email-already-in-use') {
          showDialog(
            context: context,
            builder: (context) => AlertDialog(
              backgroundColor: Color(0xFF226089),
              content: Text(
                'Account already exists',
                style: kIntertextstylewhitemedium,
              ),
            ),
          );
        } else if (e.code == 'invalid-email') {
          showDialog(
            context: context,
            builder: (context) => AlertDialog(
              backgroundColor: Color(0xFF226089),
              content: Text(
                'Please enter a valid email',
                style: kIntertextstylewhitemedium,
              ),
            ),
          );
        }
      }
    }
  }

  void whereToGo() async {
    var sharedPref = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    var isLoggedIn = sharedPref.getBool(KEYLOGIN);

    if (isLoggedIn != null) {
      if (isLoggedIn) {
        Navigator.pushReplacement(
            context,
            MaterialPageRoute(
              builder: (context) => HomePage(),
            ));
      }
    }
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _email.dispose();
    _password.dispose();
    _name.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.white,
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
          children: [
            Image.asset(
              'assets/Images/Apex_Memo_logo.png',
              height: 80,
              width: 50,
            ),
            Expanded(child: Lottie.asset('assets/Images/Login_animation.json')),
            Text(
              'Apexmemo: Your Simple Solution for Tasks and Notes!',
              textAlign: TextAlign.center,
              style: GoogleFonts.inriaSerif(
                fontSize: 25,
              ),
            ),
            SizedBox(
              height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.03,
            ),
            Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                  left: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.1,
                  right: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.1),
              child: ElevatedButton(
                style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                  backgroundColor: Color(0Xff226089),
                  minimumSize: Size(95, 15),
                  foregroundColor: Colors.white,
                  shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(10)),
                  ),
                ),
                child: Padding(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 20, bottom: 20),
                  child: Row(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                    children: [
                      Icon(Bootstrap.google),
                      SizedBox(
                        width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.1,
                      ),
                      Text(
                        'Continue with Google',
                        style: TextStyle(
                          fontSize: 16,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
                onPressed: () {
                  signInWithGoogle(context);
                },
              ),
            ),
            SizedBox(
              height: 10,
            ),
            Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                  right: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.1,
                  left: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.1),
              child: ElevatedButton(
                style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                  foregroundColor: Colors.white,
                  backgroundColor: Color(0Xff000000),
                  shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(10)),
                  ),
                ),
                onPressed: () {
                  showDialog(
                      context: context,
                      builder: (context) => AlertDialog(
                            backgroundColor: Colors.white,
                            title: Text(
                              "Sign In / Sign Up",
                              style: TextStyle(
                                color: Colors.black,
                              ),
                              textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                            ),
                            content: Column(
                              mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                              children: [
                                ElevatedButton(
                                  style: kElevatedButtonStyle,
                                  child: Text(
                                    'Sign Up',
                                    style: kTextColor,
                                  ),
                                  onPressed: () {
                                    Navigator.of(context).pop();
                                    showDialog(
                                      context: context,
                                      builder: (context) => SimpleDialog(
                                        contentPadding: EdgeInsets.all(20),
                                        backgroundColor: Color(0xFFFFFCFF),
                                        title: Text(
                                          'Sign Up',
                                          style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
                                        ),
                                        children: [
                                          SingleChildScrollView(
                                            scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
                                            child: Form(
                                              key: _formkey,
                                              child: Column(
                                                mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                                                children: [
                                                  TextFormField(
                                                    validator: (value) {
                                                      if (value == null ||
                                                          value.isEmpty) {
                                                        return 'Please Enter Username';
                                                      }
                                                      return null;
                                                    },
                                                    controller: _name,
                                                    style: TextStyle(
                                                      color: Colors.black,
                                                    ),
                                                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                                                      border:
                                                          OutlineInputBorder(
                                                        borderRadius:
                                                            BorderRadius
                                                                .circular(20),
                                                      ),
                                                      prefixIcon:
                                                          Icon(Icons.person),
                                                      hintText: 'Name',
                                                    ),
                                                  ),
                                                  SizedBox(
                                                    height: 10,
                                                  ),
                                                  TextFormField(
                                                    validator: (value) {
                                                      if (value == null ||
                                                          value.isEmpty) {
                                                        return 'Please Enter Email';
                                                      }
                                                      return null;
                                                    },
                                                    controller: _email,
                                                    style: TextStyle(
                                                      color: Colors.black,
                                                    ),
                                                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                                                      border:
                                                          OutlineInputBorder(
                                                              borderRadius:
                                                                  BorderRadius
                                                                      .circular(
                                                                          20)),
                                                      prefixIcon:
                                                          Icon(Icons.mail),
                                                      hintText: 'Email',
                                                    ),
                                                  ),
                                                  SizedBox(
                                                    height: 10,
                                                  ),
                                                  TextFormField(
                                                    validator: (value) {
                                                      if (value == null ||
                                                          value.isEmpty) {
                                                        return 'Please Enter Password';
                                                      }
                                                      return null;
                                                    },
                                                    keyboardType: TextInputType
                                                        .visiblePassword,
                                                    controller: _password,
                                                    obscureText: _obscuretext1,
                                                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                                                      suffixIcon: IconButton(
                                                        icon: Icon(_obscuretext1
                                                            ? Icons
                                                                .visibility_off
                                                            : Icons.visibility),
                                                        onPressed: () {
                                                          setState(
                                                            () {
                                                              _obscuretext1 =
                                                                  !_obscuretext1;
                                                            },
                                                          );
                                                        },
                                                      ),
                                                      border:
                                                          OutlineInputBorder(
                                                        borderRadius:
                                                            BorderRadius
                                                                .circular(20),
                                                      ),
                                                      prefixIcon:
                                                          Icon(Icons.key),
                                                      hintText:
                                                          'Create Password',
                                                    ),
                                                  ),
                                                ],
                                              ),
                                            ),
                                          ),
                                          SizedBox(height: 20,),
                                          ElevatedButton(
                                            style: kElevatedButtonStyle,
                                            onPressed: () {
                                              if (_formkey.currentState!
                                                  .validate()) {
                                                setState(() {
                                                  email = _email.text;
                                                  name = _name.text;
                                                  password = _password.text;
                                                });
                                              }
                                              _signUpWithEmail();
                                            },
                                            child: Text(
                                              "Sign Up",
                                              style: kTextColor,
                                            ),
                                          ),
                                          SizedBox(
                                            height: 5,
                                          ),
                                          Center(
                                            child: GestureDetector(
                                              onTap: () {
                                                Navigator.pop(context);
                                              },
                                              child: Text(
                                                "Cancel",
                                                style: TextStyle(
                                                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                                  fontSize: 15,
                                                  color: Color(0xFFD35E5E),
                                                ),
                                              ),
                                            ),
                                          ),
                                        ],
                                      ),
                                    );
                                  },
                                ),
                                ElevatedButton(
                                  style: kElevatedButtonStyle,
                                  child: Text(
                                    'Sign In',
                                    style: kTextColor,
                                  ),
                                  onPressed: () {
                                    Navigator.of(context).pop();
                                    showDialog(
                                      context: context,
                                      builder: (context) => SimpleDialog(
                                        backgroundColor: Color(0xFFFFFCFF),
                                        contentPadding: EdgeInsets.all(20),
                                        title: Text(
                                          'Sign In',
                                          style: TextStyle(
                                            color: Colors.black,
                                          ),
                                        ),
                                        children: [
                                          Column(
                                            mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                                            children: [
                                              TextFormField(
                                                // cursorColor: Color(0xFF226089),
                                                controller: _email,
                                                style: TextStyle(
                                                  color: Colors.black,
                                                ),
                                                decoration: InputDecoration(
                                                  prefixIcon: Icon(Icons.mail),
                                                  border: OutlineInputBorder(
                                                    borderRadius:
                                                        BorderRadius.circular(
                                                            20),
                                                  ),
                                                  hintText: 'Email',
                                                  labelStyle: TextStyle(
                                                    color: Colors.black,
                                                  ),
                                                ),
                                              ),
                                              SizedBox(
                                                height: 10,
                                              ),
                                              TextFormField(
                                                controller: _password,
                                                style: TextStyle(
                                                  color: Colors.black,
                                                ),
                                                decoration: InputDecoration(
                                                  suffixIcon: IconButton(
                                                    icon: Icon(_obscuretext2
                                                        ? Icons.visibility_off
                                                        : Icons.visibility),
                                                    onPressed: () {
                                                      setState(
                                                        () {
                                                          _obscuretext2 =
                                                              !_obscuretext2;
                                                        },
                                                      );
                                                    },
                                                  ),
                                                  prefixIcon: Icon(Icons.key),
                                                  border: OutlineInputBorder(
                                                    borderRadius:
                                                        BorderRadius.circular(
                                                            20),
                                                  ),
                                                  hintText: 'Password',
                                                  labelStyle: TextStyle(
                                                    color: Colors.black,
                                                  ),
                                                ),
                                                obscureText: _obscuretext2,
                                              )
                                            ],
                                          ),
                                          SizedBox(height: 20,),
                                          ElevatedButton(
                                            style: kElevatedButtonStyle,
                                            onPressed: _signInWithEmail,
                                            child: Text(
                                              'Sign In',
                                              style: kTextColor,
                                            ),
                                          ),
                                          SizedBox(
                                            height: 5,
                                          ),
                                          GestureDetector(
                                            onTap: () {
                                              Navigator.of(context).pop();
                                            },
                                            child: Center(
                                              child: Text(
                                                'Cancel',
                                                style: TextStyle(
                                                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                                  fontSize: 15,
                                                  color: Color(0xFFD35E5E),
                                                ),
                                              ),
                                            ),
                                          )
                                        ],
                                      ),
                                    );
                                  },
                                ),
                              ],
                            ),
                          ),);
                },
                child: Row(
                  children: [
                    Icon(Icons.mail),
                    SizedBox(
                      width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.1,
                    ),
                    Padding(
                      padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 20, bottom: 20),
                      child: Text(
                        'Continue with Email',
                        style: TextStyle(
                          fontSize: 16.0,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),
            SizedBox(
              height: 50,
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I was expecting that ontap of Icon button password will be visible and vice versa and yet it is not happening i tried set state also passed a boolea, logic seems to be correct as per my knowledge. If anyone can help me solve this issue i would really appreciate it. Do let me know if you need any help understanding this code.

Comment: You can use StateFulBuilder  to update dialog state  `builder: (context) => StateFulBuilder`

Comment: I checked the code is perfect and the button is working only when it is closed and opened again so my guess is the dialog box is not changing state

Comment: Might be this is the context issue. If you provide parent context then it will change your UI.

Answer (score 0):

So the problem solved itself when I Made 2 new stateful widgets,1 for signup and another for sign-in with all the logic and their respective simple dialogs and called them to the main file it now works.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).